# Using vite - Uncaught SyntaxError: ambiguous indirect export: default

Tags: javascript, vite

I'm using vite 4.3.9.

My src\utils\markdown.jsx looks like this :

```
import fs from 'fs';
import path from 'path';
import remark from 'remark';
import html from 'remark-html';

const contentDirectory = path.join(process.cwd(), 'content');

const getContentBySlug = (slug) => {
  const fullPath = path.join(contentDirectory, `${slug}.md`);
  const fileContents = fs.readFileSync(fullPath, 'utf8');
  const processedContent = remark().use(html).processSync(fileContents);
  return processedContent.toString();
};

const markdownUtils = {
  getContentBySlug
};

export default markdownUtils;
```

But I keep getting in console that "Uncaught SyntaxError: ambiguous indirect export: default", as a result of which the page is blank.

Comment: Have you tried with `export default const markdownUtils = .....` ?

Comment: Still no luck. I think the issue was that this is 100% client-side application and I was trying to read the filesystem in the browser ?

Comment: But your error comes from Vite - not from the browser. Perhaps these may help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73813721/syntaxerror-ambiguous-indirect-export-default-error-when-importing-my-own-clas

Comment: The issue was that I was trying to use fs from a client-side ReactJS project. I replaced fs with await fetch(fullPath) and it its working now.